# IOS In-app purchases Sandbox testing - Does not unlock Content

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, storekit, receipt-validation

When testing our app in a sandbox account for in-app purchases it gives the verification that the transaction has completed, but it does not UNLOCK the content that was purchased.

For example:

1. Store
2. Buy Level Packs

   Result: Transaction Successful, but the packs are NOT unlocked.

Steps Taken:

- Created multiple test user accounts.
- Only build to device when completely signed out of everything
- Only signing in once prompted from in-app purchase.
- App removed and freshly installed with each test account

Is there something we are missing or have to do in order for the content to actually be unlocked after a successful in-app purchase?

Fairly new to development, Thanks

Comment: You have to write your own code to make the content available based on whether the user completed an in-app purchase or not.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose is your responsibility to "unlock" the new level when you receive a receipt from Apple.